# How to set constraints for UIPickerView to UITableViewCell? (Like in Apple DateCell Sample)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, uipickerview

I'm using Apple's DateCell sample Xcode project to figure out how to use a UIPickerView inside of a UITableViewCell, but I'm having some trouble figuring out the constraints that the sample code has set up for the UIDatePicker in the storyboard.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html

It says that the UIDatePicker has a constraint relative to the actual UITableViewCell, but when I try to set up a constraint between the two, I can't. Ctrl-dragging from the picker to the cell doesn't highlight the cell. I tried doing it with the cell's content view rather than the cell itself, but that doesn't quite produce the same result as in the sample code's storyboard.

These are the constraints set up by the project for the date picker:
[image]

And for the cell:

[image]

What the sample's storyboard looks like:

[image]

How can I reproduce the above image using constraints?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear what you want to accomplish or what is not working.

Comment: Basically, I'm asking what the steps are to reproduce the same constraints and dimensions of the date picker in the sample.





What I describe in my second paragraph (after the link) is basically what I'm having trouble with. In the sample project, I see that the date picker is constrained to the table view cell with a height of 216. I have no idea how to make this happen. I can only constrain the date picker to the cell's content view, which isn't what's in the sample's storyboard, and doesn't produce the same result.

Comment: Did you try connecting in a new project? Did you try deleting the connection and reinserting it?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to recreate the sample project in a brand new project, but with a UIPickerView instead of a date picker. So far, I was able to constrain it to the picker's superview, which is the cell's content view: http://i.imgur.com/9Q1HlYc.png
But again, this isn't exactly what the sample project shows to have done.

Comment: I tried to figure out the same thing. My conclusion is that you can't create a constraint between the datePicker and the UITableViewCell itself, at least not in storyboard. Maybe you can by adjusting the Storyboard source code. I'm not quite sure why Apple decided to add the constraint directly to the cell, because adding it to the cell's contentView also works, just make sure the contentView has the same height as the datePicker. I someone can explain it, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the sample's static height was not what I wanted to use anyway, since I have some cells with lots of text that need to have variable heights for each cell. So instead of the approach in the sample which grabs the height of the picker cell from the pre-defined storyboard size, I used UITableViewAutomaticDimension to automatically fit all of my cells for height. If you don't want auto height, it's still pretty easy to adapt the following solution to set the height to a static value, as I mention in step 3.

1. Set tableview row height to auto when the view loads:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0; // Set your average height here.
       self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }
   ```
2. Add an estimated height so that it works properly (at least in iOS 8). If you don't add this, you might get some buggy behavior when it draws the cell heights.

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }
   ```
3. For **auto** height, remember to remove the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` definition if you have one, as it could interfere with the auto settings.

   ```
   // Don't define this at all if you want the picker cell to have auto height.
   //- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   //{ }
   ```

   - If you want to use a **static** height for the picker cell, then define the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` function and just return the static value here instead of using the auto dimension like the sample does it. Example would be something like this:

     ```
     - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         // This would return the static height for the picker, but auto heights for the rest of the cells.
         return ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath] ? self.pickerCellRowHeight : UITableViewCellAutoDimension);
     }
     ```
   - And then you'd modify the sample to set your static height instead of grabbing it from the frame value in `viewDidLoad`.

     ```
     // obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
     //UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
     self.pickerCellRowHeight = 216;//CGRectGetHeight(pickerViewCellToCheck.frame);
     ```
4. Rather than trying to recreate the same constraints from the sample, I told storyboard to Reset to Suggested Constraints for the UIPickerView, and then added one more. It added the first two in the picture, and then I just added one more for aligning the center X. My view happened to have the shown numbers from the auto settings but yours may be different.

   [image: Storyboard of cell and constraints]

   [image: Reset to suggested constraints]
5. In case you haven't already done it, part of making the picker work is to make sure the dataSource and delegate for the UIPickerView are set to the view controller using storyboard and control clicking and dragging.

   [image]